# How can I add an id to a created element?

Tags: javascript, html, createelement

If I use:

```
var something = document.createElement("div");
```

Is it possible to give an id to this brand new div?

Comment: something.setAttribute("id", "idOne");

Comment: `something.id = 'whatever';`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating an element like

```
var something = document.createElement("div");
```

then, You can assign an id to it dynamically by

```
something.id = "my_div";
```

where `my_div` will be the id that will be assigned to the `div` that you created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

something.setAttribute("id", "idOne");